# How to determine unknown class in image classification model such as mobilenet?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have `n` classes and a one `unknown`.

`Unknown` is not included in the training set as the way is not explored as yet by me.

I trained the mobilenet(or inception-v3) for `n` classes. The confusion matrix is very good.

Now if an `unknown-class` image comes in for prediction, the model predicts it as any of the n classes. `Which is clearly misclassified`.

The confidence also comes near by `0.998`, which makes it difficult to filter out. Otherwise known class object of n trained classes is classified at same confidence.

I tried keeping a class which does not include any feature set of n classes i.e. sort of negative sampled class as unknown class. As output, the confusion matrix goes very bad. Bad enough not to go further with that. This I am still going through.

How to determine unknown class using neural network? That it doesn't fall in any known class classification.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a research problem, its not a programming problem.

Comment: @ericyue, I'm dealing with a similar problem. I was wondering if you've found a way to define the 'unknown' class?

Comment: @Stef did you guys find a solution for this?

Comment: any final result??

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with a similar problem in the past. You have to keep the following points in mind:

a. When you introduce the "unknown" class as your "n+1"th class, you should keep in mind that this class should represent the same variance as you would expect during your live/prod run. To elaborate, if you assume images from m different categories to come which are not a part of your training label, then all such images should be represented in this "unknown" label. This will help to bring the confidence score down for these "out-of-scope" images.

b. Additionally, once you bring the confidence score down with the help of above method, you can set a threshold on the confidence score.

The above two steps combined can help you filter out the "out-of-scope" images. I  hope this helps for you. In case of further clarification, let me know.

Comment: can you suggest any practical example of it?